# How to read the filename of a csv file in ruby

Tags: ruby, csv

I need to read the filename of a csv file to extract some information about what to do with the data inside the file. How do I read the filename?

e.g. I will get a file called 200_SomeTestName.csv. The file will contain details of the test to be created. I'm required to create a test called SomeTestName for the student who has an id of 200.

Comment: I will get it in a shared Dropbox folder.

Comment: I'm thinking of reading all the files in the folder and storing the names in a variable. That seems to be the only way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can list all the CSV files in the dropbox folder and check if they match the pattern. Then extract the information you need and create the test:

```
Dir.glob('yourdropboxfolder/*.csv').each do |filename|
  name = File.basename(filename, '.csv')
  if (match = /(\d+)_(.*).csv/.match(name))
    student_id = match[1]
    test_name = match[2]
    create_test_for(student_id, test_name, File.read(filename))
  end
end
```

Not sure if you need to extract the values from the filename or if this information is also in the file.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, this is the way I'm going about it.